# Creating multiple elements from a point in a doubly linked list

Tags: list, insert, linked-list, element

I've been working on this for about a day and haven't been able to put a series of nodes in the middle of a linked list. In all, the program I'm trying to write takes a string, another string and an integer, and places the second string at the integer location in the linked list made from the first string. I've tried quite a few strategies but they've all met with unresponsive programs and segmentation faults. My code is below:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    char j;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
}node_t;

void print(node_t *head)
{
    node_t *curr = head;
    while(curr)
    {
        printf("\n%d%c\n", curr->number, curr->j);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

void insert(int index, node_t *head, node_t *tail, char* string)
{
    node_t *curr = head;
    node_t *newNode = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));;
    node_t *newPrev = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));;
    node_t *newNext = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));;
    int i;

    while(curr->number!=index)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    //printf("\n%d%c\n", curr->number, curr->j);

    newNode->prev = curr;
    newNode->next = curr->next;
    newNext = curr->next;
    curr->next = newNode;
    curr = curr->next;

    for(i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
    {
        curr=(node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        curr->number = i;
        curr->j = string[i];

        curr->prev = tail;
        tail->next = curr;
        tail = curr;
    }

    newNext->prev = curr;
}

int main()
{
    node_t *curr,*head,*tail;

    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    int i;
    int index = 0;
    char* inputString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);
    char* inputString2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);

    printf("Please input a string: ");

    gets(inputString);
    printf("%s\n", inputString);

    for(i=0; i<strlen(inputString); i++)
    {
        curr=(node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        curr->number = i;
        curr->j = inputString[i];
        curr->next = NULL;
        if(tail)
        {
            curr->prev = tail;
            tail->next = curr;
        }
        tail=curr;
        if(!head)
        {   
            head=curr;
        }
    }

    printf("Please input a string: ");

    gets(inputString2);
    printf("%s\n", inputString2);

    printf("Please input a valid index: ");

    scanf("%d", &index);
    while(index>strlen(inputString)||index<0)
    {
        printf("A valid index. ");
        scanf("%d", &index);
    }
    printf("%d\n", index);

    insert(index, head, tail, inputString2);

    print(head);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd be eternally grateful if anyone could provide a way to insert the second string into the linked list as elements. I've determined that it works as far as identifying the node specified by the integer, but beyond that I'm not sure. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now my issue is that the program puts an rubbish node at the correct place, but then creates the nodes at the end of the list.

Comment: Sorry, a medical emergency required my attention, but I'll try to fix what you've mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've renamed my struct, assigned space to newNode upon declaration and I think I'm already passing head and tail into the insert function. The problem I have now is that it appears to insert a node at the correct place, but it is rubbish, and then adds onto the list at the end. I will update the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are still so many problems with your code that it is probably impossible to help you in this forum without simply giving you "the answer". You might try a different website.

Some hints:

Since it is possible for head and/or tail to be modified in the insert function, you need to pass in their addresses, not just their values. I.e.,

```
void func(node_t **head) {
    // dereference head (with *) to use it
    *head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
}

void another_func() {
    node_t *head = NULL;
    func(&head);    // pass the address of head
}
```

newPrev is unused (are you compiling with a proper warning level? With gcc, add the -Wall flag).

newNext doesn't need any malloced space since it is used to point to previously-allocated space.

And there are other errors (logic errors) more difficult to describe.

My advice it to rewrite it. Declare another struct called list to hold the head and tail pointers. Write a function called make_node to create and initialize a new node given a character (and a number if you think that's necessary). Write a function called make_list that takes a string and returns a list of its characters. In the insert function, use make_list to make a list from the string to be inserted and then modify the pointers to insert it into the first list.

Storing the index numbers in the nodes is unnecessary and actually complicates things since to keep them in order you'd need to update the indices in the original list after the insertion. You can simply keep a count of how many nodes you've looped through to know the index of a node.

Adding the C language tag to your question may bring others in to help you.

Comment: Thanks, it appears a clean slate is probably the best thing for it at this point.